# Created exact copy of Magento root folder now its redirecting to live site and not local

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have cloned the contents of the Magento root directory along with the database on my local server, now when I try to visit my local server by using the IP address it will redirect me to the live site on the remote server. Is there a file I need to edit that does this redirect?

Answer (score 1):

Magento saves website's base url in `[prefix_]core_config_data table`. You need to change the value for paths:

`web/unsecure/base_url`

and

`web/secure/base_url`

in this table.

Also check that whether there are any changes in database login credentials on your local server. If yes, then you need to change it accordingly in:

`[website's root directory]/app/etc/local.xml`

Now delete **cache** and **session** folders under `[website's root directory]/var` folder.

Answer (score 1):

Just run following sql query in your mysql server:

```
update core_config_data
set value = 'http://[your-new-host]/'
where path = 'web/unsecure/base_url';

update core_config_data
set value = 'http://[your-new-host]/'
where path = 'web/secure/base_url';
```

please change [your-new-host] to your host name and also don't forget "**/**" at the end.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things to fix, and two things to follow up with.

Database: (this is the most likely issue)
update domain inside of: core_config_data
reference: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/update_site_url_in_core_config_data

DB Config File: app/etc/local.xml
this must be updated with your local DB settings to access the correct DB internally.

You will also want to clear your Magento cache.
store/var/cache/*

Browser:
Clear your local cache, just to be safe.

Cheers!